# Work out value of variables when given the sum of all combinations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

If I have a grid of the total of all possible combinations of the variables when they're multiplied, how can I work out the value of each individual variable?

For example:

Multiplication grid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC2Uk.png

Those are the sums when each of the combinations of the variables are multiplied... how can I work out the value of each variable?

i.e:   $a = 5,\; b = 2,\; c = 7,\; d = 3,\; e = 2,\; f = 5,\; g = 3,\; h = 7$?

Comment: For real numbers, no. You can scale $a,b,c,d$ by same number $\lambda$ and $e,f,g,h$ by $\lambda^{-1}$, you get same grid. If you are working with positive integers, maybe.

Comment: @achillehui: right,  but, apart from the $\lambda$ , the vectors can be determined also for real (or even complex) values, iff the matrix is actually obtained by the diadic product of two vectors (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You must solve a system having $16$ equations and $8$ unknowns, so there is little hope to get a solution in general.

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{llll}
 a e=10 & b e=4 & c e=14 & d e=6 \\
 a f=25 & b f=10 & c f=35 & d f=15 \\
 a g=15 & b g=6 & c g=21 & d g=9 \\
 a h=35 & b h=14 & c h=49 & d h=21 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$$\left\{a,\frac{2 a}{5},\frac{7 a}{5},\frac{3 a}{5},\frac{10}{a},\frac{25}{a},\frac{15}{a},\frac{35}{a}\right\}$$

In this case you are lucky. There are *infinite* solutions. If you want all integer entries you must have $a=5$  and the other follow like this

$\{a=5,b=2,c=7,d=3,e=2,f=5,g=3,h=7\}$

Comment: you might be interested to know that there is actually a "general" approach, as reported in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is standardly written as
$$
{\bf x}\;\overline {\bf y}  = {\bf x} \otimes \;{\bf y} = {\bf A}
$$
where the overline denotes the transpose, and the whole is known as a [Dyad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics),
made from vectors $\bf x, \; \bf y$.

Given $\bf A$, you want to solve for the vectors.

We shall premise some properties of the Dyad.

Calling $h$ the dimension of the vectors, if we multiply at the right by any of the $h-1$ vectors normal to $\bf y$
$$
{\bf 0} = \overline {\bf y} \,{\bf n}_{\,{\bf y}} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf 0} = {\bf x}\;\overline {\bf y} \,{\bf n}_{\,{\bf y}}  = {\bf A}\,{\bf n}_{\,{\bf y}} 
$$
we get a nullvector.
Same if we multiply $\overline {\bf A}$ to the left by the transposed of any vector normal to $\bf x$.
$$
{\bf 0} = \overline {{\bf n}_{\,{\bf x}} } \;{\bf x}\;\overline {\bf y} \, = \overline {{\bf n}_{\,{\bf x}} } \;{\bf A}
$$

Therefore $\bf A$ shall have a left and right null-space of dimension $h-1$, and 
consequently **$\bf A$ shall have rank $=1$**.

It is easy to see that the LU decomposition of $\bf A$ is given by
$$
{\bf A} = \left( {\matrix{
   {x_{\,1} } & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   {x_{\,2} } & 1 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
    \vdots  & {(0) \vdots } & {(1) \ddots } & {(0) \vdots }  \cr 
   {x_{\,h} } & 0 & {(0) \cdots } & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   {y_{\,1} } & {y_{\,2} } &  \cdots  & {y_{\,h} }  \cr 
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \cr 
   0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
and that the only *generally* non-null eigenvalue is equal to ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf y}$, which
is then null as well if the two vectors are normal.

In conclusion, provided that the rank of the matrix be $1$, you can recover the vectors by its LU decomposition (or from the nullspace, or eigenspace).
Of course, as underlined by *achille hui*, the vectors you get are well determined, less a constant multiplier/divisor.